# Creating vectors with respect to remainder

Tags: r

I have the problem following : Let's say we consider numbers from 1 to 102. I want to create four vectors a,b,c,d in such way :

Vector a takes value 1 if a=4k+1 and 0 otherwise

Vector b takes value 1 if a=4k+2 and 0 otherwise

Vector c takes value 1 if a=4k+3 and 0 otherwise

Vector d takes value 1 if a=4k and 0 otherwise

for some integer k.

**My work so far**

```
a<-b<-c<-d<-c()
for (i in 1:102)){
  if (i%%4==1){a[i]<-1}
  else (a[i]<-0)
}
for (i in 1:102){
  if (i%%4==2){b[i]<-1}
  else (b[i]<-0)
}    
for (i in 1:102){
  if (i%%4==3){c[i]<-1}
  else (c[i]<-0)
}
for (i in 1:102){
  if (i%%4==0){d[i]<-1}
  else (d[i]<-0)} 
}
```

**Question**

Is there any faster way to do that without using 4 loops ?

Answer (score 4):

`%%` is vectorized, so you don't need any loops. And `ifelse` is a vectorized version of `if(){}else{}`.

```
rem = 1:102 %% 4
a = ifelse(rem == 1, 1, 0)
b = ifelse(rem == 2, 1, 0)
c = ifelse(rem == 3, 1, 0)
d = ifelse(rem == 0, 1, 0)
```

The `ifelse` makes it clear that you are getting a 1 or 0 output, but you can also do, e.g., `a = as.integer(rem == 1)` to coerce the TRUE/FALSE directly to 1 and 0 instead of using `ifelse`. It's a little more efficient, though perhaps a little less clear.